# Discord bot doesn't give back roles after unmute member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I've made a bot that can mute and umute user. The main problem is, after getting mute and give unmute, the roles not back again
Here's what I've tried

```
const mainRole = [`791144820810842163` , `794825576602533898` , `791144908240060426` , `791144966474563624` , `791145298072305685` , `791145926344966185` , `791146191336505414` , `791146355552682034` , `792565793568587796` , `795357387794939904` , `795358283623432213` , `798804993468530699` , `791146747367653387`];
module.exports = {
    name: `unjail`,
    description: "this is unjail command!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You cant unjail person because you are not staff/co owner/owner");
            let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Peasant');
            let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed');
 
            let = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
 
            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
            memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been unjailed`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand the logic of the code without comments, but if I understood it correctly, I guess the variable `mainRole` is undefined or empty, at the moment of the `unjain`(unmute) event, may you check it via `console.log` first?

Also, I have no idea, how you overwrite the `const mainRole` variable with `let`

Comment: hmm so I need to add the Roleid to the let main role right? or ? sorry I'm new to programming so I didn't really understand. But when I tried with the mute command it works fine the const mainrole

Comment: what version of Discord.js are you using? And could you please print here, what exactly stored is variables: `mainRole` and `muteRole` at the moment of the command?

Comment: have you understood my answer yet? Or something for you, have not been clear?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code logic fine and it should work as intended. So let's describe it and try to solve the problem.

```
    //extract mentioned user, by this command
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (target) {
        //target mentioned user from discord server members
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
        //check permissions for user that using the command
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You cant unjail person because you are not staff/co owner/owner");
        //find roles Peasant in server cache that should be returned and role Jailed
        let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Peasant');
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed');
        //?????? What have been here?
        let = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
        //return roles
        memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
        memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been unjailed`);
    } else {
        message.channel.send('Cant find that member!');
    }
```

How actually should work this code, by the correct logic:

1. No `const mainRole = ['791144820810842163',...]` predefining before the module.exports.
2. The following code will return only one role (Peasant in this case) to the unjailed person. But it could return even more roles, if you could store all the roles from the user, at the moment of *muting*. So you'll need some kind of storage for that and don't forget to add the following logic, to the command that actually muting users.

Writing to JSON file via `fs` module or [any DBaaS for free-for-dev](https://free-for.dev/#/?id=dbaas) should help you with that.

> *If you have a huge Discord server with thousands of users, I highly recommend Mongo Atlas for that.*

```
module.exports = {
  name: `unjail`,
  description: "this is unjail command!",
  execute(message, args){
    //return exeption for lack of permission
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You cant unjail person because you are not staff/co owner/owner");

    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!target) return message.channel.send(`Can't find mentioned user!`);
    const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    if (!memberTarget) return message.channel.send(`Can't find mentioned user!`);
    
    /**
    * At this point, we should return from the store the original roles for a user to restore
    * But since we don't have any storage, let's just return the only available role, Peasant, and remove the role Jailed
    */
    let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Peasant');
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed');

    memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
    memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
    
    message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been unjailed`);
  }
}
```